# Temporizador com o Chronometer

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo e nele usa o temporizador, clicando no *play* para iniciar e o pause para ele pausar, só que quando eu clico novamente no *play* ele zera, teria como fazer para continuar contando o tempo?

código java:

```
public class FutebolSimples extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton imgButton_play, imgButton_pause, imgButton_1, imgButton_2;
    private TextView txt_valor1, txt_valor2;
    private int contador = 0;
    private int contador1 = 0;
    private Chronometer reloginho;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_futebol_simples);


        imgButton_1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_1);
        imgButton_2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_2);
        imgButton_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_play);
        imgButton_pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_pause);
        reloginho = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        txt_valor1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_valor1);
        txt_valor2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_valor2);

        imgButton_play.setEnabled(true);
        imgButton_pause.setEnabled(false);
        imgButton_1.setEnabled(false);
        imgButton_2.setEnabled(false);


        imgButton_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgButton_play.setEnabled(false);
                imgButton_pause.setEnabled(true);
                imgButton_1.setEnabled(true);
                imgButton_2.setEnabled(true);

                reloginho.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                reloginho.start();
            }
        });

        imgButton_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgButton_play.setEnabled(true);
                imgButton_pause.setEnabled(false);
                imgButton_1.setEnabled(false);
                imgButton_2.setEnabled(false);

                reloginho.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer que continue a contar a partir do valor que estava quando parou ou deve considerar o tempo que passou até continuar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para não zerar o valor você tem que somar o `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` com o tempo que foi pausado com o `.stop()` usando uma variável qualquer inicializada com `0`.  Exemplo:

```
long tempoPausado = 0;
```

Atualize o valor da variável quando você parar o cronómetro assim:

```
tempoPausado = reloginho.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
mChronometer.stop();
```

Assim pode-se usar essa variável para ajustar o cronômetro antes de iniciá-lo:

```
reloginho.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + tempoPausado);
```

Boa Sorte! =)

Comment: Obrigado.... =)

Comment: @Nathan Por nada! Precisar, dê um grito! =D